# Retrieving string data from $.get javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue with java script. This is my first time using javascript.

Code:

```
$.get( url, function( data ){

    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

   alert(obj.result);
}
```

The server returns a simple json string `{"result":"aaaa"}`
How can I extract this json string from the response?
When i run this code alert shows undefined.

Comment: Just call `obj.result`.

Comment: Right away you have a `{` mismatch. Also by the way what is the issue? Can you explain it.

Comment: You don't need to begin each line with `{`. That is going to cause syntax errors that will prevent your code from doing *anything*. Until you fix that, there's not much use in proceeding with any other problems you have. I suggest you find a decent tutorial on JavaScript and at least get a handle on the fundamental syntax before trying to use jQuery and/or AJAX.

Comment: I am sorry for poor editing. i have updated the code. The alert message shows undefined when doing this.

Comment: You need to verify obj has the property result. Do this by setting a break point or using console.log(obj) to print the object to the console so you can inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be not reproducible.

```
JSON.parse('{"result":"aaaa"}').result
```

yields "`aaaa`".

Do some more debugging like this:

```
$.get( url, function( data ){

    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    for (key in obj) {
        alert(key + ": " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

This will iterate over all the keys in your returned json. Hopefully, you'll have a key named "result" in there.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you don't actually need to parse it.

```
$.get( url, function( data ){

    alert( typeof data ); // object

    alert( data.result ); // aaaaa

});
```

Without a `dataType` being specified, [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will default to making an "*Intelligent Guess*" and parse accordingly.

If you would rather parse it yourself, you can specify `'text'` as the `dataType`.

```
$.get( url, function( data ){

    var obj = JSON.parse( data );

    alert( obj.result ); // aaaaa

}, 'text');
```